# If $\int_{iT}^{(i+1)T}f(t)dt \to 0$ as $i\to\infty$ for arbtrary $T>0$, then does $f(t)$ converge to $0$ essentially?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable for any subinterval of $[0,\infty)$. If $\int_{iT}^{(i+1)T}f(t)dt \to 0$ as $i\to\infty$ for arbtrary $T>0$, then does $f(t)$ converge to $0$ essentially? In other words, is there a function $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}g(t) = 0$ and $f(t) = g(t)$ a.e. $t\in[0,\infty)$?

So far, what I can think is that for each $T>0$, there exists a subsequence of $f_i:[0,T]\to R$, $f_i(t) = f(iT+t)$, $i=1,2,\dots$, that converges to $f_0(t) \equiv 0$ a.e. on $[0,T]$. But I cannot find a way to use that $T>0$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the case. Note that any Lebesgue-integrable function satisfies your conditions, but not every such function vanishes at infinity. Simply choose $f$ to be zero everywhere, except on intervals of the form $[n-2^{-n}, n+2^{-n}]$. On these intervals, let $f(n) =1$ and interpolate linearily inbetween. The resulting function is bounded, integrable, satisfies your condition but does not vanish at infinity. With a bit more effort you can choose this function to be smooth too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.